# HashMap with 8 million entries becomes slow

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have a HashMap with 8 million Point2D's mapping to a LinkedList.

```
private Map<Point2D,LinkedList<RoadEdge>> adjacencyList;
```

Everything works as it should, but it takes very long time for me to get data from the HashMap. Is there any alternative, that I can use to optimize getting data out?

I am willing to compromise the time it takes to `put()` in favor of the time it takes to `get()`.

Comment: Checking for collisions is always a good starting point when your hashmap is slow. The difference between a poorly and well implemented `hashCode()` method can be enormous.

Comment: probably not helpful, but I'd move to a database. :)

Comment: This here *might* be helpful: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue235.html

Comment: Looking things up in a `HashMap` should be fast. Possible reasons: `Point2D` may not have a good `hashCode` method so that you get hash collisions, or not the map lookup is slow, but something else, like traversing a long `LinkedList`.

Comment: You might consider using a data structure specifically designed for spatial lookups. For instance, if your "keys" are fixed, you might use a K-d tree, or similar.

Comment: Database is not possible at the moment. All the points in the hashmap is very close (within decimals) - could that cause a lot of collisions?

Comment: What is the actual lookup that you're doing here? Are you looking up exact points, or are you doing nearest-neighbour lookups?

Comment: Actual lookups. I have points and I want to find the edges related to the points for a A* search.

Comment: In A*, a LRU cache should help

Comment: I would not blame the `HashMap` in the first place. See [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)…

Comment: I think it wouldn't matter changing to ArrayList, as we are iterating through all of them.

Comment: @Hedam `ArrayList` is faster to iterate than a `LinkedList`.

Comment: How about using some cache, like EhCache? http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/get-started/introduction.html

Comment: Maybe a splay tree type structure would be useful too.

Comment: Please show `Point2D.hashCode` implementation

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Default implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing is to check the distribution of hashcode. First check that, but with a minor change. The hashcode of a `Key` inside a map is re-hashed internally via:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

So you should really re-hash your hashcode with this function and than later check how it is distributed.

Generally under a good distribution, your `TreeNodes` (this is how a bucket is set-uo for many entries) are very fast to be found. For a bucket that would have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` entries it would take at most `32` steps to find it. That happens because the bin is transformed into a *perfectly balanced red-black tree*.

Searching inside a `Map` in general is `O(1)`. Searching a bin with `TreeNodes` is `O(logn)`. And searching inside a LinkedList is `O(n)` - much worse then the previous ones.

But that is the time it takes to find a *single* Entry in the map. If you further need to get the element from the `LinkedList` that means additional  time(worse then finding the entry in the map)

Also for so many entries it is critical to specify the `loadFactor` and `initialCapacity` *initially* (at least initialCapacity), before putting the elements into the map. This is because of re-hashing and moving of elements for another bucket (potentially). If you first put them *all* and than just try to find them, without altering the `Map` - this will not be a problem when searching...

But generally unless you measure and measure correctly this might not be the problem you are facing. You might be looking into the wrong direction.

Comment: First thing is to check is where the actual bottleneck is, e.g. using a profiler. If I see `LinkedList` in the declaration, I’m not willing to accept the statement that the *hashmap* is the problem, without any prove…

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check the hash function of your key (Point2D). It should be well distributed or you'll have a lot of collisions. See Eugene's answer for an explanation on the beauty that is the HashMap.

Secondly, depending on how you want to access the data (by which I mean you try to get the same object a lot), you can use a cache, but do this only if you can't change the `hashCode`.

Here is my implementation of a LRU cache from another project. It might speed some things up (it's not wonderful code and does unchecked casting, but should work in most cases).

```
package util;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CachedHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 36215319740415714L;

private LRUCache<K, V> cache;
private LRUCache<K, Boolean> containsCache;

public CachedHashMap(int cacheSize){
    containsCache = new LRUCache<>(2*cacheSize);
    cache = new LRUCache<>(cacheSize);
}

@Override
public V put(K key, V value){

    cache.put(key, value);
    containsCache.put(key, true);
    return super.put(key, value);

}

@Override
public boolean containsKey(Object key){

    if(containsCache.containsKey(key)){
        return containsCache.get(key);
    }

    boolean contains = super.containsKey(key);

    containsCache.put((K) key, contains);

    return contains;

}

@Override
public V remove(Object key){
    containsCache.remove(key);
    cache.remove(key);
    return super.remove(key);
}

@Override
public V get(Object key){
    if(containsCache.containsKey(key)){
        if(!containsCache.get(key))
            return null;
    }

    V value = cache.get(key);
    if(value != null)
        return value;

    value = super.get(key);

    K keyCast = (K) key;
    if(value != null){
        containsCache.put(keyCast, true);
        cache.put(keyCast, value);
    }else{
        containsCache.put(keyCast, false);
    }

    return value;
}

class LRUCache<A, B> extends LinkedHashMap<A, B> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5958373482978477783L;

private int cacheSize;

  public LRUCache(int cacheSize) {
    super(16, 0.75f, true);
    this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
  }

  protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<A, B> eldest) {
    return size() >= cacheSize;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: And if you search for a lot of non-existent points, a Bloom filter can be useful too.

Comment: I can tell you that the difference betweens all 8 million points are in the decimals. Will that affect the default hashCode?

Comment: won't the xor mean that if x and y are equal, the hashcode will always be 0?

Comment: The coords are always 6.xxxx and -55.yyyy. If that produces the same hashCode I really see the issue.

Comment: The cached HashMap made the average case go down to almost nothing.

Comment: @Hedam of course it did, you have a cache now. But still you are hiding the real problem and that's ok if you are ok with that

Comment: @Hedam That's great. But Eugene really is right. If speed becomes a problem again (like it did in the project where i used this cache). Cache misses will still be quite slow. As a hash function I suggest not including the exponent part of the double in your hash, since they are always the same. Then, instead of xor, use standard prime number approuches.

Comment: Why are you doing this double lookup in `if(containsCache.containsKey(key)){ return containsCache.get(key); }`? Your `containsCache` only contains the present keys or, in other words, always maps to `true`, so why not simply `if(containsCache.containsKey(key)){ return true; }`? Well, or why not using a `Set` in the first place?

Comment: @Hedam `difference between 8 million points are in the decimals`, but than later you give an example where the precision is just 4 digits after the dot. 4 digits can not provide 8 million entries...

Comment: The containscashe also contains false, for when the map doesn't have the given key

Comment: @Eugene, that was an example. I use all significant digits in the float Point2D.

Answer (score 2):

To prove a point, here is a `jmh` test that searches for an entry in maps that contain `10, 10_000 and 10_000_000` entries. You *can see* from the results that the search is `constant` - O(1). The problem is elsewhere in your code. Even if you don't understand the code the results are just readable numbers(see at the end).

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Level;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.TearDown;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

@BenchmarkMode(org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class TwoMapsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {

        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(EightMillionsTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .jvmArgs("-ea", "-Xms10g", "-Xmx10g")
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    // the check bellow assert map.size() == numberOfElements; can absolutely fail
    // fingers crossed that it does not.

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class Map_10 {

        int numberOfElements = 10;

        public Map<Point2D, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        public Point2D mightBePresent = null;

        public Point2D isPresent = null;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setUp() {
            int randomInsideHowManyBoundry = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(numberOfElements);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {

                double[] d = generateTwoPoints(-3.0, 3.9999, 4);
                Point2D p = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);

                if (isPresent == null && i == randomInsideHowManyBoundry) {
                    isPresent = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);
                }
                map.put(p, i);
            }

            assert map.containsKey(isPresent);
            assert map.size() == numberOfElements;
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Iteration)
        public void tearDown() {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class Map_10_000 {

        int numberOfElements = 10_000;

        public Map<Point2D, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        public Point2D mightBePresent = null;

        public Point2D isPresent = null;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setUp() {
            int randomInsideHowManyBoundry = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(numberOfElements);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {

                double[] d = generateTwoPoints(-3.0, 3.9999, 4);
                Point2D p = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);

                if (isPresent == null && i == randomInsideHowManyBoundry) {
                    isPresent = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);
                }
                map.put(p, i);
            }

            assert map.containsKey(isPresent);
            assert map.size() == numberOfElements;
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Iteration)
        public void tearDown() {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class Map_10_000_000 {

        int numberOfElements = 10_000_000;

        public Map<Point2D, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        public Point2D mightBePresent = null;

        public Point2D isPresent = null;

        @Setup(Level.Iteration)
        public void setUp() {
            int randomInsideHowManyBoundry = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10_000_000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; ++i) {

                double[] d = generateTwoPoints(-3.0, 3.9999, 4);
                Point2D p = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);

                if (isPresent == null && i == randomInsideHowManyBoundry) {
                    isPresent = new Point2D(d[0], d[1]);
                }
                map.put(p, i);
            }

            assert map.containsKey(isPresent);
            assert map.size() == numberOfElements;
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Iteration)
        public void tearDown() {
            map.clear();
        }
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int mightBePresentMap_10(Map_10 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.mightBePresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int isPresentMap_10(Map_10 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.isPresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int mightBePresentMap_10_000(Map_10_000 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.mightBePresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int isPresentMap_10_000(Map_10_000 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.isPresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int mightBePresentMap_10_000_000(Map_10_000_000 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.mightBePresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Benchmark
    public int isPresentMap_10_000_000(Map_10_000_000 map) {
        Integer x = map.map.get(map.isPresent);
        return x == null ? -1 : x;
    }

    private static double[] generateTwoPoints(double upperBound, double lowerBound, int precision) {
        double x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(lowerBound, upperBound);
        x = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

        double y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(lowerBound, upperBound);
        y = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

        return new double[] { x, y };
    }
}
```

> And the actual results:

```
  Benchmark                                          (howManyEntries)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent                      1  avgt    5   8.787 ± 0.259  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent                     10  avgt    5   9.988 ± 0.283  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent                    256  avgt    5   9.146 ± 2.081  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent                  10000  avgt    5   8.871 ± 0.574  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent                1000000  avgt    5   8.894 ± 0.676  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.isPresent               10000000  avgt    5  10.884 ± 5.623  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent                 1  avgt    5   4.607 ± 0.175  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent                10  avgt    5   4.713 ± 0.944  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent               256  avgt    5   5.283 ± 0.511  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent             10000  avgt    5   8.944 ± 0.144  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent           1000000  avgt    5  10.256 ± 0.121  ns/op
hashmap8Millions.EightMillionsTest.mightBePresent          10000000  avgt    5   8.764 ± 0.504  ns/op
```

Notice that these are **nano-seconds**, this is by far not slow...